# Mouse Wheel click event is not firing on IE and FireFox

Tags: javascript

i am gonna download my file on mouse event. file is outside the server. here is my code that download file. this code is working perfectly on chrome that i want. but not working on IE and Firefox.. What should i do to fix this issue. same code work for all.

js

```
function Download(url) {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = url;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = "test" + ".mp4";

    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', { // mouse wheel event
        "button": 1,
        "which": 1
    });
    save.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

html

```
 <a href="#" onclick="Download('www.testserver.com/mediafiles/abc.mp4')">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>
 </a>
```

Comment: where is the code that *handles* the `mouse wheel click event` you mention?

Comment: sory my bad I have edit the js code please check again

Comment: Why do you need the mouse wheel click event? You already added the `target='_blank'` property which should be enough in itself to open the URL in a new tab. Dispatching a click event should be enough.

Comment: i want to download the file on anchor click. but problem is. it is running the not download the video. that's why i do it.

Comment: try `onclick="Download('www.testserver.com/mediafiles/abc.mp4'); return false;`

Comment: changing   "button": 1, to   "button": 0, fixed it

Comment: @JaromandaX it is not working

Comment: @nima_moradi it is playing the video. i don't want to play. i want to download the video

Comment: in Firefox is show dialog to save or open , <a href="#" onclick="Download('HarvardXCS50W-V000200_DTH.mp4')">
        <p>hi</p>
    </a>

Comment: it works in opera and chrome too ,and if i use remote link it's working in edge too https://edx-video.net/HarvardXCS50W-V000200_DTH.mp4 <br> but not in IE

Comment: @nima_moradi i have tested on your code it's playing the video.. :(